# Required field validation message is consistency

Tags: radio-buttons, required-fields

1.In first question, if user has not selected radio button then i am showing the required field validation message as "Selection of Likelihood is required".

2.In second question, if user has not selected radio button then i am showing the required field validation message as "Response is required".Because if i take the actual question's text ,then the validation message will be "Selection of Is your principal place of bussiness different from your registered address? is required."

So the problem is, my required field validation messages are not consistent across the application.So is it a good practice to use generic required fields validation messages across the application?[image]

Comment: Why not simply put "Required" next to the field instead of trying to express it as a full sentence?   Being next to the field already implies that the field is required, so no detailed explanation should be needed, and then the issue of consistency becomes moot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use a generic message, backed up with strong visual validation cues.**

To avoid having to refer to the names of fields, just use a generic message e.g. (depending on the style of your copy)

> We found some issues with your form submission. Please fix these in order to continue.

Then use some space near the form field to explain the problem e.g.

'Answer Required', 'Invalid email address format', etc.

[image]

I made a couple of other suggestions in the mockup above.

- "Likelihood' seems unnecessarily terse as a label, and could use more context, even if it seems obviously related to the field above it.
- Rather than have a really long field label in the form of a question that proposes the concept of different states and making the user click 'Yes' or 'No', consider making the radio button labels descriptions of the various states.